# $f(x)=||x||^2 x$ is bijective on $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ such that $f(x)= ||x||^2 x$. I want to show that $f$ is bijective.

We know local bijection using inverse function theorem at all points other than zero.Can we say a global inverse exists?

Comment: I actually don't get why people are down-voting this one, it seems the op has actually tried it a bit, and has a well-formed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convenient to write your function as 
$$f(x) = ||x||^3 \cdot \frac{x}{||x||}$$

More generally, you can have 
$$f(x) = \phi(||x||) \cdot \frac{x}{||x||}$$

It is perhaps safe to assume extra that $\phi(0) = 0$. Now, if your function of $1$ variable $\phi\colon [0, \infty)\to [0, \infty)$ is bijective then $f$ is also bijective and the inverse will be

$$f^{-1}(y) = \phi^{-1}(||y||) \cdot \frac{y}{||y||}$$

Check how it works in our example.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** 
$$\big\| \lVert x\rVert^2 x \big\| = \| x \|^3$$

To prove 1-1, if $f(x)=f(y)$ use the above to show first that $\|x\|=\|y\|$.

To prove onto, if for given $x$ you want $f(x)=y$ what does the hint tell you about $\|x \|$ and $\| y\|$?